# Setup 2008 Server with Remote Desktop Services/Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I have a 2008 server that I can access via remote desktop as I am the domain admin at my work environment. We are installing some software that will require a handful of users to login and use the software. I've always been confused to what type of licenses I need and the steps to install Remote Desktop Services. Do I just need to buy 5 CALs and install them once I install the required features? It looks like I'll need to install the Remote Desktop Session Host and Remote Desktop Licensing Service? Do I need any license for this part of the install, or does the 5 CALs cover me if I only need 5 concurrent users max?

Comment: This is a ***programming Q&A site*** - [take the 5 minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) .This is not the place to ask sysadmin / server questions. Check out [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) for these kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to install both Remote Desktop Session Host and Remote Desktop License Server. Please use the steps mentioned in  [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/supportingwindows/archive/2013/09/20/rd-licensing-configuration-on-windows-server-2012.aspx) article to setup your license server.

You would need as many number of Per User licenses as many users you want to have access to RDSH.

Thanks
Silvia Doomra